# Vim package vimerl installation problems on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, vim, erlang

Vim 7.3
Installation that described in read me is simple: copy everything from tar archive to ~/.vim
I did so. Nothing was happened. No highlight... no plugin help. Nothing
On Lion I dont have this problem.

May be I have to put something to vimrc

Comment: Which platform (I guess some OS X), and which Vim package (I think there are multiple on Mac OS)? Also, which README do you refer to? It's hard to help with so little information. Also, this installation issue probably better belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain lion.

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov 20 2012 08:59:23)
.Installed from macports, install under superuser. 

Readme link
https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl/blob/master/README

Comment: Ah, much better. Did you do `:helptags`, as instructed in the README?! And check `:scriptnames` output whether the plugin (and after editing an Erlang file) ftplugin files of the plugin have been sourced.

Comment: Scriptnames output 1: ~/.vimrc
  2: ~/.vim/plugin/erlang_skel.vim
  3: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  4: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
  5: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
  6: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  7: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
  8: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
  9: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 10: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 11: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 12: /opt/local/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim

Comment: ":helptags" asks me for additional argument. read me does not mentioned any args. ":help vimerl" return not found error.

Comment: That would be `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` for you. The `:scriptnames` output looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, so I'm not sure if this will help but I solved the same problem by cloning the Git repository into my ~/.vim/bundle directory (as opposed to ~/.vim) and then adding the line `call pathogen#helptags()` to the top of my .vimrc (after calling pathogen infect).